# SQL - apply single value to all rows in table

Tags: sql, database, weighted-average

I have two tables - one called "customer_data" and one called "weighted_average_rate_charged".

Customer_data

| First Name | Last Name | City | Daily_Rate | Total_paid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jim | Carter | Dallas | $100.00 | $600.00 |
| James | Franklin | Houston | $150.00 | $900.00 |
| Lily | Smith | Dallas | $90.00 | $540.00 |
| Frank | Masters | Dallas | $95.00 | $680.00 |
| Jennifer | Brown | Houston | $100.00 | $590.00 |

Weighted_Average_Rate_Charged

I have used the following query:

```
select
City,
sum(Daily_Rate * Total_Paid)/sum(Total_Paid) as WA_Rate
from customer_data
group by
City
```

To get my weighted average per city. Now, what i want to do is take the max number, which according to the output below is 130.2013:

| City | WA_Rate |
| --- | --- |
| Houston | $130.2013 |
| Dallas | $95.1648 |

And essentially create a new table which is the same as customer_data but with an additional column called "Max_WA_daily" which shows $130.2013 for all entries in that table.

Example:

| First Name | Last Name | City | Daily_Rate | Total_paid | Max_WA_daily |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jim | Carter | Dallas | $100.00 | $600.00 | $130.2013 |
| James | Franklin | Houston | $150.00 | $900.00 | $130.2013 |
| Lily | Smith | Dallas | $90.00 | $540.00 | $130.2013 |
| Frank | Masters | Dallas | $95.00 | $680.00 | $130.2013 |
| Jennifer | Brown | Houston | $100.00 | $590.00 | $130.2013 |

I have tried a range of different join options and nested select statements, but cant get this to work. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

We could use analytic functions here, with a two tier aggregation approach:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SUM(Daily_Rate * Total_Paid) OVER (PARTITION BY City) /
        SUM(Total_Paid) OVER (PARTITION BY City) AS WA_Rate_City
    FROM customer_data
)

SELECT First, Last, City, Daily_Rate, Total_Paid,
       MAX(WA_Rate_City) OVER () AS Max_WA_daily
FROM cte;
```

The first CTE turns out the WA rates partitioned by each city.  The query below that finds the max such value, but across the entire table.

Answer (score 0):

Windows functions can be used here. It allows us to have aggregations on different levels within one view [table] which you need.
Additionally, I would suggest not to use Subquery and use Common Table Expressions (CTE)

**Step 1:** Calculate the weighted average [the one you already did]

**Explaination of Step 1:**

Here in the OVER() clause you have defined the aggregation level just like you did in the group by above. Which means you can still select all the other colums [first name, last name, daily rate, total paid and NOT have them in the Partition BY clause [the beauty of windows functions]. In windows functions you define the aggregation layer within Partition by which is City in your case)

**STEP 2:** Get Max() Value [The one you need]

**Explaination:** here we didn't add the aggregation layer as we just need the max value from the column weighted average.Hence partition by and OVER is left empty

```
With Weighted_Average AS ( 
    Select
        city,
        first_name,
        last_name,
        city,
        daily_rate,
        total_paid,
        sum(daily_rate * total_paid) OVER(PARTITION BY city)
             /
            sum(total_paid) OVER(PARTITION BY city) AS weighted_average
        
        FROM 
          customer_data
        group by
          city
        )
        
    Select
      *,
    MAX(weighted_average) OVER() AS max_weighted_average

    FROM
      Weighted_Average
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the Following

```
 select FistName,LastName,City,Daily_Rate,Total_Paid,
 (select max(WA_Rate) from Weight_Average) as Max_Wa_Rate
 from customer_data
```

Answer (score 0):

select
City,sum(Daily_Rate*Total_paid)/sum(Total_Paid) as WA_Rate
from customer_data
group by City

select *,
(select sum(Daily_Rate*Total_paid)/sum(Total_Paid) as WA_Rate from customer_data
where City in ('Dallas')
group by City) as Max_WA_Rate from customer_data